# Nginx - Block POST requests if a GET request has not been made before

Tags: nginx, firewall, spam

I have tried to make a rule to block POST requests if the IP address has not made a GET request before, to decrease the number of spam bots/ddos attack.
I would not like to use captchas because they are not very friendly to the end-user.

I got this idea based on this post:
[First Line of Defense: Blocking Bad POST Requests Using NGINX Rate Limiting | reverb.com](https://product.reverb.com/first-line-of-defense-blocking-bad-post-requests-using-nginx-rate-limiting-507f4c6eed7b)

This is what I have at the moment:

Maps ip address(http_x_forwarded_for catch proxy aswell) to $limit variable if request is of type POST

```
  map $request_method $limit {
    default         "";
    POST            $http_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

Do I need to create a list of whitelist on GET request or even a cookie, then check it when POST request "kicks-in".
I dont know if it can be done at Nginx.
I didn't want to do it on PHP.